# How Can I use contructor in kernel.php file?

Tags: php, laravel

I wanna use constructor method like below for dependency injection, How can I use the repository pattern in this case?

The code bellow does not work and it gives me the container error

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use App\Console\Commands\CrawlUSD;
use App\Console\Commands\CrawlUSDT;
use App\Repository\Contracts\Trade\TradeConfigurationRepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        CrawlUSD::class,
        CrawlUSDT::class,
    ];

    protected $tradeConfigurationRepository;

    public function __construct(TradeConfigurationRepositoryInterface $tradeConfigurationRepository)
    {
        $this->tradeConfigurationRepository = $tradeConfigurationRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('crawl:USDT')->{$this->tradeConfigurationRepository->getTheNewestConfigForUSDT()->trade_configuration_update_per_minutes}();
        $schedule->command('crawl:USD')->{$this->tradeConfigurationRepository->getTheNewestConfigForUSD()->trade_configuration_update_per_minutes}();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

I've already bounded the interface in its own provider

and I've added the parent constructor with the dependency but I still get the error bellow

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [App\Repository\Contracts\Trade\TradeConfigurationRepositoryInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Console\Kernel]. in /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1038
Stack trace:
#0 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(839): Illuminate\Container\Container->notInstantiable()
#1 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(712): Illuminate\Container\Container->build()
#2 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(826): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve()
#3 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(651): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve()
#4 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(811): Illuminate\Container\Container->make()
#5 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(980): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make()
#6 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(900): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass()
#7 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(861): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveDependencies()
#8 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(712): Illuminate\Container\Container->build()
#9 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(826): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve()
#10 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(283): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve()
#11 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(826): Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#12 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(712): Illuminate\Container\Container->build()
#13 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(826): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve()
#14 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(651): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve()
#15 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(811): Illuminate\Container\Container->make()
#16 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/artisan(33): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make()
#17 {main}
  thrown in /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1038
root@development:/home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale# php artisan cache:clear
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [App\Repository\Contracts\Trade\TradeConfigurationRepositoryInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Console\Kernel]. in /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1038
Stack trace:
#0 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(839): Illuminate\Container\Container->notInstantiable()
#1 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(712): Illuminate\Container\Container->build()
#2 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(826): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve()
#3 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(651): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve()
#4 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(811): Illuminate\Container\Container->make()
#5 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(980): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make()
#6 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(900): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass()
#7 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(861): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveDependencies()
#8 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(712): Illuminate\Container\Container->build()
#9 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(826): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve()
#10 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(283): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve()
#11 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(826): Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#12 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(712): Illuminate\Container\Container->build()
#13 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(826): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve()
#14 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(651): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve()
#15 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(811): Illuminate\Container\Container->make()
#16 /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/artisan(33): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make()
#17 {main}
  thrown in /home/amir/mine/projects/tether-sale/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1038
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem a couple of days ago, here is how you can solve this problem

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use App\Console\Commands\CrawlUSD;
use App\Console\Commands\CrawlUSDT;
use App\Repository\Contracts\Trade\TradeConfigurationRepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        CrawlUSD::class,
        CrawlUSDT::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $repo = $this->app->make(TradeConfigurationRepositoryInterface::class);

        $schedule->command('crawl:USDT')->{$repo->getTheNewestConfigForUSDT()->trade_configuration_update_per_minutes}();

        $schedule->command('crawl:USD')->{$repo->getTheNewestConfigForUSD()->trade_configuration_update_per_minutes}();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct(Application $app, Dispatcher $events, TradeConfigurationRepository $tradeConfigurationRepository)
{
    $this->tradeConfigurationRepository = $tradeConfigurationRepository;
    parent::__construct($app, $events);
}
```

This class extends `ConsoleKernel`. You have to add all params from the parent constructor to your and then add repo param.
You can't set the interface as type hinting in the constructor, because it has to create an object from type hinting, and it's impossible with the interface. Use certain class instead of interface. Have a look at `Dependency injection` description

Comment: thanks, but it did not work and I dded the error to the question